# wso2 installation issue- publisher and devportal are not loading up

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, wso2, wso2-api-manager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esKh0.png)I am trying to install wso2 api manager. The installation is done, all deployments are running but im getting issue with publisher and devportal. They are not able to load settings after the login.

There are 4 portal,

1. [www.abc.com/carbon](http://www.abc.com/carbon)
2. [www.abc.com/admin](http://www.abc.com/admin)
3. [www.abc.com/publisher](http://www.abc.com/publisher)
4. [www.abc.com/devportal](http://www.abc.com/devportal)

Carbon and admin are working. But publisher and devportal are not working. It's been so many days, but I am unable to figure out the issue

Made changes in configmaps and tried lots of iterations. But couldn't solve the issue

Update: logs my mysql_db shows these error:

```
[2023-08-25 05:20:53,588]  WARN - DataEndpointGroup No receiver is reachable at URL Endpoint/Endpoints [tcp://wso2am-pattern-1-am-2-service:9611], will try to reconnect every 30 sec
[2023-08-25 05:20:54,591] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://wso2am-pattern-1-am-2-service:9711
2023-08-19T12:08:39.534755Z 258 [Note] Aborted connection 258 to db: 'WSO2AM_SHARED_DB' user: 'wso2carbon' host: '10.124.1.24' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2023-08-19T12:08:39.534858Z 250 [Note] Aborted connection 250 to db: 'WSO2AM_SHARED_DB' user: 'wso2carbon' host: '10.124.1.24' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2023-08-19T12:09:06.226166Z 1718 [Note] Got an error reading communication packets
2023-08-19T12:09:25.843402Z 1723 [Note] Aborted connection 1723 to db: 'WSO2AM_SHARED_DB' user: 'wso2carbon' host: '10.124.0.24' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2023-08-19T12:09:25.843468Z 215 [Note] Aborted connection 215 to db: 'WSO2AM_SHARED_DB' user: 'wso2carbon' host: '10.124.0.24' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```